# Multiple pipenv virtual environments in single project

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

**The scenario:** I have a locally cloned github repo with multiple branches. Each branch needs potentially different dependencies.

**The question:** I would like to switch between these branches as I work and therefore would like multiple `pipenv` virtual environments (one per branch). How can I achieve this, given that `pipenv` by default associates a single virtual environment with the project root folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out each branch into a separate directory (e.g., using [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)). Because each branch would have a separate directory, `pipenv` would work without any additional changes.